# Evaluate $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n \pi^{-n}$ CALCULUS 3

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I'm having a hardtime evaluating the following sum
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n \pi^{-n} $$
The answer to this is $$ \frac{\pi}{(\pi -1 )^2}$$

Attempt : I tried taking the derivative of this but I get an ugly expression involving $\ln $, I also tried splitting into two sums but $\sum n $ diverges, which is not what I want, therefore I'm just lost.

EDIT :

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{(1-x)} &= \sum x^n \\
\frac{-x}{(1-x)^2} &= \sum n x^n \\ 
\frac{-x}{x^{2n}(1-x)^2} &= \sum nx^{-n}
\end{align*}
  That's where I got to, but what to do with the $x^{2n}$ on the left side ?

Also another small question, how do I show that 
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^{-n} = \frac{1}{x-1} $$ i.e. the inverse of $x^n $ Maclaurin series

Thank you

Comment: Take derivative of the series $x^{n}$ and substitute $x = \frac{1}{\pi}$, then multiply by $\pi$.

To work out $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n$, multiply this series by $(1-x)$ and see what you get.

Comment: $\dfrac1{1-\frac1x}=1+\dfrac1x+...,$ so $\dfrac1{x-1}=\dfrac x{x-1}-1=\dfrac1{1-\frac1x}-1=...$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n x^n= x \sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1}= x \biggl(\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{n}\biggr)',$$
and it converges to $\;x\Bigl(\dfrac 1{1-x}\Bigr)'$ for $|x|<1$.

Comment: Honestly, I wouldn't have found this trick during an exam, can you show me how to arrive at the solution using my attempt at the solution provided in the post ? I'm genuinely  curius. Because i have a $\frac{-x}{x^{2n}}$ on the left side, and i don't know what to do with that ! My final answer can't have $n$  in  it...

Comment: Actually, you have almost my method at the second step of your edit (except for a small sign error  for the derivative of $\frac 1{1-x}$. At the third step, I really don't know  where you can go to, as there's a problem with the radius of convergence of the geometric series when you replace $x$ with $\pi$. Furthermore you divide both sides by $x^{2n}$, but in the sum, $n$ is a dumb variable!